# Deleting images from gallery remain as attachment

Tags: media, gallery

Process creating a gallery:

1. I create a post with post format *gallery*
2. I add images from "Add media", note I don't use "Create gallery" but insert pictures into the post
3. update

then I have a php side

```
$attachments = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $atts['order'], 'orderby' => $atts['orderby'] ) );
```

this code comes from `gallery_shortcode` function in **media.php**.

it works perfect, but when I try to delete image from post, no matter how I try it it is still there. I have not tried this but obviously deleting image permanently from media would work, but I want this images to still remain there.

how to delete them as attachments for this images from post editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to detach images is to select Media Library from the menu, Find the images you want to detach, and click the `Detach` link in the `Uploaded to` column. This will remove the value saved in `post_parent` for the attachment.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see that option, can you be more specific. When I open the post and click **Add Media** button, I choose **Media Library** tab inside **Insert Media** tab (other tabs are: **Create Gallery** and **Featured Image**, but clearly I don't want them). I click on image but I don't have `Detach` option. only **Insert into post**

Comment: It's not under Posts, it's under the Media Library menu item in the main menu.

Comment: this is what is see http://screenshot.co/#!/2665753f04 there is no detach button there. when I click gallery (in **Uploaded to**) it just brings me to that post

Comment: @CBeTJlu4ok May be you need the list view of media library (not the attachment) :)

Comment: yaaay! thanks man. whats wrong with it, if I want to use columns, detaching is not accessible? that definitely wrong. I spend so much time just to find this damn button.